# Can C++ objects have block scope?

Tags: objective-c-blocks, objective-c++

Can C++ objects have block scope? For example, is this ok: (it crashes)

*(Go easy, I'm still learning C++)*

```
__block Poco::Thread* lastThread;

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        Poco::Runnable* worker = new  Worker(_counter, "worker" + Poco::NumberFormatter().format(i));
        Poco::Thread* workerThread = new Poco::Thread();
        workerThread->start(*worker);
        lastThread = workerThread;
    }
});

lastThread->join(); //wait so we can watch what happens.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is valid, nothing wrong with declaring that pointer `__block` scope. But your code will crash because `lastThread` does not point to any object when `join()` is invoked. You run that block asynchronously, so almost certainly `lastThread->join()` is reached before `lastThread` will point to the worker thread.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the pointer can have block scope. The reason that it crashes is that there is a race between `lastThread->join()` and the initialization of the pointer.